# history.start() function does not work in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am new trying to make use Routers in backbone but my `Backbone.history.start()` method does not work. It gives me below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'start' of undefined
```

Here is my code

```
(function ($) {
window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Router: {}
};

window.Template = function (id) {
    return _.template( $('#' + id).html() );
};

App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routers: {
        '': 'index'
    },

    index: function () {
        console.log('index page');
    }
});

var r = new App.Router;
Backbone.history.start();
})(jQuery);
```

How can I remove this error?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code, I've made a copy & paste on jsfiddle and it's working without a error [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rB3Dd/1/)... Maybe there's a problem on how you have declared Backbone or Underscore?

Comment: @Ingro your link returns false in console whereas it should log `index page`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you do not have any `routes` in your Router. 
You have `routers` and it's not the same :)

Comment: I am new to backbone. Could you please give some code? Where should I make change in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Change routers to routes

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index'
    },

    index: function () {
        console.log('index page');
    }
});
```

Now create object of routers and start backbone history.

```
app = App.Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```